# Configure websocketd and PATH variable

Tags: linux, websocket

I am trying to use this project ([websocketd](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd/wiki/Download-and-install)), but the third step is not working:

```
1-download the platform specific archive //done
2-extract files to folder of your choice or extract executable only // done
3-add the location of websocketd to your PATH variable
```

Currently i have this PATH

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/var/www/cpu-stats/websocketd
```

But when i run this code:

```
websocketd --help
```

I will get:

```
bash: websocketd: command not found
```

websocketd location

```
/var/www/cpu-stats/websocketd
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just add the folder "/var/www/cpu-stats" to your path without the executable file name.